# WebSphere Portal 8.5 Exception after start

Tags: websphere-portal

I have installed WebSphere Portal 8.5 with CF 07 Fix Pack and database is Oracle 11g as back-end.

Today, after starting Portal Server and hitting the URL for wps/portal it gives me error like Error 404: There is no content available.

After looking into SystemOut.log file I came to know that there is some DB related error as follows :

```
    [9/22/15 12:05:53:422 IST] 000000eb WSJdbcConnect W   CWWRA8650W: Error closing a JDBC child wrapper, com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement@8f3a5140
com.ibm.websphere.ce.cm.StaleConnectionException: Closed Statement
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:540)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapExceptionHelper(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:626)
    at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.mapException(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:685)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.mapException(AdapterUtil.java:2267)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcUtil.mapException(WSJdbcUtil.java:1191)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcPreparedStatement.closeWrapper(WSJdbcPreparedStatement.java:557)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:242)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.closeChildWrappers(WSJdbcObject.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:240)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcObject.close(WSJdbcObject.java:195)
    at com.ibm.icm.ci.Datastore$DataSource.releaseConnection(Datastore.java:551)
    at com.ibm.icm.ci.ConnectionService.releaseConnection(ConnectionService.java:125)
    at com.ibm.icm.ci.Ticket.endAction(Ticket.java:365)
    at com.ibm.icm.ci.Ticket.endSchemaAction(Ticket.java:315)
    at com.ibm.icm.ci.schema.impl.SchemaService.retrieveContentTypes(SchemaService.java:298)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.nodetype.NodeTypeManagerImpl.loadAllNodeTypes(NodeTypeManagerImpl.java:218)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.RepositoryImpl.loadNodeTypeCache(RepositoryImpl.java:746)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.TicketImpl.getNodeTypeManager(TicketImpl.java:714)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.WorkspaceImpl.getNodeTypeManager(WorkspaceImpl.java:2749)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.NodeImpl.getNodeType(NodeImpl.java:1324)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.service.access.WPSAccessManagerImpl.createObjectID(WPSAccessManagerImpl.java:2398)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.service.access.WPSAccessManagerImpl.isGranted(WPSAccessManagerImpl.java:2079)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.service.access.WPSAccessManagerImpl.isGranted(WPSAccessManagerImpl.java:717)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.service.access.WPSAccessManagerImpl.isGranted(WPSAccessManagerImpl.java:669)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.NodeImpl.checkPermissions(NodeImpl.java:5361)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.WorkspaceImpl.getRootNode(WorkspaceImpl.java:2420)
    at com.ibm.icm.jcr.WorkspaceImpl.getRootNode(WorkspaceImpl.java:2387)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel.loadRepositoryNode(JCRWebdavTreeModel.java:741)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.mm.MMJCRWebdavTreeModel.loadRepositoryNode(MMJCRWebdavTreeModel.java:159)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel$1.run(JCRWebdavTreeModel.java:571)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel$1.run(JCRWebdavTreeModel.java:568)
    at com.ibm.wps.ac.impl.UnrestrictedAccessImpl.run(UnrestrictedAccessImpl.java:84)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.ac.ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.execute(ExecuteUnrestrictedCommand.java:90)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel.getRootUUID(JCRWebdavTreeModel.java:579)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel.getRootItem(JCRWebdavTreeModel.java:502)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel.getTreeModel(JCRWebdavTreeModel.java:646)
    at com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel.getTreeModel(JCRWebdavTreeModel.java:62)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.utils.DefaultFilesFinder.getFilePathInfos(DefaultFilesFinder.java:193)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.profile.ProfileHelper.getAllProfilePathInfos(ProfileHelper.java:374)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.profile.ProfileListImpl.loadModel(ProfileListImpl.java:283)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.data.DataCenter.initializeProfileListModel(DataCenter.java:578)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.data.DataCenter.getProfileResultMap(DataCenter.java:619)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.profile.ProfileListImpl.getProfile(ProfileListImpl.java:143)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.profile.CorPortalProfileListImpl.getProfile(CorPortalProfileListImpl.java:94)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.contribution.ContributionRegistryHomeImpl.getThemeCapabilties(ContributionRegistryHomeImpl.java:862)
    at com.ibm.wps.resourceaggregator.contribution.ContributionRegistryHomeImpl.getThemeCapabilties(ContributionRegistryHomeImpl.java:783)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.RenderInfoHelper.getModuleThemeCapabilitiesInternal(RenderInfoHelper.java:568)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.RenderInfoHelper.getAllModuleThemeCapabilities(RenderInfoHelper.java:581)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.RenderInfoHelper.handleCapabilities(RenderInfoHelper.java:604)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.phases.WPActionPhase.execute(WPActionPhase.java:1073)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.phases.AbstractActionPhase.next(AbstractActionPhase.java:146)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.callPortal(Servlet.java:264)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:576)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:356)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:780)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:103)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1265)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1230)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:779)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter$ExtendedFilterChain.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:110)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtensionFilter.doFilter(ExtensionFilter.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.SupportedLocalesFilter.doFilter(SupportedLocalesFilter.java:112)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilterWithoutProjectID(ProjectIdFilter.java:405)
    at com.ibm.wps.project.filter.ProjectIdFilter.doFilter(ProjectIdFilter.java:319)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.preview.PreviewFilterImpl.doFilter(PreviewFilterImpl.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:440)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerGzip.internalDoFilter(ContentHandlerGzip.java:730)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerGzip.doFilter(ContentHandlerGzip.java:471)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:103)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ServletSubstitutionFilter.doFilter(ServletSubstitutionFilter.java:119)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.wps.devicesupport.WorklightFilter.doFilter(WorklightFilter.java:166)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:960)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1064)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3837)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1864)
```

The above stack trace is just the top part of actual stack trace.

If some one have any solution of how to solve this problem, It is great help for me.

Comment: Can you provide the exact trace?  Also have you tested the database connections via Integrated Solutions Console.  Go to Resources-JDBC-Data Sources.  Select all data sources and click the test connection button.  Then resolve any errors.

Comment: @MattM I have checked the connection, and it is working fine from there, and exact trace is nearly of 3000 lines, how can I provide over here?

Comment: I have re-transferred my DB to Oracle and that resolves all my errors as of now.

Comment: @MattM Again error comes up, I have uploaded the full stack trace over here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9hel73vagjie9g/SystemOut.log?dl=0. If you have any idea, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reviewing the full trace it looks like you have an issue with the JCR database on your oracle server.

JCRWebdavTree E com.ibm.wps.filestore.JCRWebdavTreeModel getTreeModel() Could not initialize TreeModel
                                 com.ibm.wps.command.CommandException: EJPFB0002E

ErrorCode:7015] During an SQL operation in the library server, an unexpected error. :ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qkaffsindex5], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

In looking at an ORA-00600 error Oracle is asking you to open a support ticket according to their site to analyze why the request failed.

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600

It is most likely a timeout error.